# GLEW does not work

Tags: opengl, glew

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

When I execute this then comes a message:
Failed to initalize GLEW

And what is the problem? This message was written by me

What can I do?

Comment: Rewrite it that way: `GLenum err = glewInit(); if (GLEW_OK != err) { std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl; }`  to see a more specific message.

Comment: Failed to initialize GLEW: Missing GL version

Comment: Then you most likely call `glewInit` before you have initialized an OpenGL context. How to do that depends on what OS you are on or what library you use to create the OpenGL context.

Comment: Oh, I have forgotten: glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); :D thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the OpenGL context is current before initializing GLEW.